# How often does gairaigo （外来語） get bikago （美化語）?

Tags: loanwords, bikago

How often does gairaigo get bikago?

[おトイレ](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%83%88%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AC) is mentioned by Wiktionary, and Wikipedia [mentions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honorific_speech_in_Japanese#Prefix_usage) it being used ironically in o-kokakōra, but I haven't come across any others.

One case where its absence is noticeable is referring to someone else's partner as a パートナー without an お before it (or a さん afterwards, for that matter)

Are there any words other than トイレ that often get お (apart from in the speech of teenage girls)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some people use [おコーヒー](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E3%81%8A%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%92%E3%83%BC%22&oq=%22%E3%81%8A%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%92%E3%83%BC%22).  Both おトイレ and おコーヒー sound like words used in a certain idiolect to me, and their use is not limited to teenage girls, but I do not know exactly what kind of people use these words.

Comment: I feel that socially high-class madams use them, and these words are also 役割語 for such people. For example, it's likely to be used by スネ夫's mother.

Comment: @sawa: Is "high-class madams" a euphemism?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm For what?

Comment: @sawa: Either an up-market prostitute, or a woman who runs a brothel.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm No. Far from that. I don't understand why take it like that. Judging from your other questions, I think you are thinking that kind of things too much in the context of Japanese. In several of your questions, you mention sexual things, genital, or prostitution.

Answer (score 9):

おタバコ is heard all the time when restaurant staff asks you if you need a seat where you can smoke.

> おタバコはお吸いになりますか Do you smoke?

おビール, おソース, おタオル I've heard as well, but less often.

I would say that 美化語 on 外来語 is not a phenomenon correlated with teenage girls, on the contrary. It strikes me as something that mainly elder women say when trying to sound elegant, although that is an obvious generalization.

Comment: +1, but choosing Tsuyoshi Ito's answer, mainly because caffeine rather than nicotine is my drug of choice.

Answer (score 2):

Bikago does not seem to have much relation with gairaigo. I think what you really meant is "how often are gairaigo used as **euphemism**?" From your examples, I feel that. And if that is your question, I think the answer is, quite often.

Comment: What do you mean by euphemism? I thought euphemism means using a vague word or phrase rather than a more specific one.

Comment: A gairaigo is not as familiar as native Japanese words to the Japanese speaking people, so it does not carry negative connotations as much.